# How to select second table structure under a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select every second `table` under a `div`.

so my html is like

```
<div class ='tableDiv'>
  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

</div>

...other stuff...

<div class ='tableDiv'>
  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>
</div>

other stuff

<div class ='anotherTableDiv'>
  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to select every second table under '`tableDiv`' div.

I tried.

```
$('.tableDiv table:nth-child(even));
```

but it doesn't work. I can't really change class name or add an ID so it's a bit difficult. Can anyone gives me a hint for it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look into jQuery.each() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's `:even` selector.

```
$('.tableDiv table:even')
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you close your quote marks. What you started with is fine except for that.