# jQuery weird issue with the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question from my last post.

[How to select second table structure under a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137160/how-to-select-second-table-structure-under-a-div)

I have a new html set and it is like

```
<div class ='tableDiv'>
  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>


</div>

...other stuff...

<div class ='tableDiv'>
  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

</div>

other stuff

<div class ='anotherTableDiv'>
  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>

  <table class='table'>
    ....
  </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to select every second table under '`tableDiv`' div.

from the last post I got.

```
$('.tableDiv table:even); as my last post answer
```

However, I now have 3 tables under '`tableDiv`' div and the selector seems to select second table from the first '`tableDiv`' and first table on the second '`tableDiv`'

It is very weird as I thought `even` will select the second one from every `div`.

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try adding an ID instead of using classes. It should be a lot easier that way.

Comment: The `:even` and `:odd` selectors are zero based so `:even` will get the first, third (index 0, 2) etc and `:odd` will get the second, fourth (index 1,3) etc http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Comment: My guess is that `:even` is taking the index of the element on the jQuery object instead of the index with relation to its siblings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/6MCAY/)***

Try using the `nth-child` selector

```
$('.tableDiv table:nth-child(2)');//not 0 based
```

Comment: Not sure what the OP wants, but this selects ***only*** the second child, and not `:even` or `:odd` children -> http://jsfiddle.net/6MCAY/1/

Comment: @adeneo - I think it is clear what the OP wants. He wants to ***`only`*** select the second child table for each tableDiv. "I am trying to select every second table under 'tableDiv' div"-OP

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the selector so it gets the even tables from within each `.tableDiv`, right now it gets all the tables in the selector, and then selects the even tables from all tables etc.

You can do this easily by using `find()` or the context selector :

```
$('table:even', '.tableDiv')
```

This wont get you the second table, but the first and third, as that is what `:even` does (as noted in the comments, it's zero based, use `:odd` instead to get the second tables)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnA6d/)

Comment: @ArnarYngvason - yes, as noted `find()` would also work, the context selector is just a shortcut for `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the class name of the third table div set to 'anotherTableDiv' but the Jquery is targeting the '.tableDiv' class. either change the name of the class or make a separate Jquery to target the third table.